# how to retrive the object data by using it's id in Django in template file (HTML file)?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template file (index.html) like this

1. Car item1
2. Car item2
3. Car item3

and when click on each of them we redirect to a template file (details.html) with a variable named {{ Car_id }} and i want to show details information about this object in this template file. How can i retrieve object from database in template file?

here is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Car

def index(request):
    latest_car_list = Car.objects.order_by('-placketName')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_car_list': latest_car_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'CarBank/index.html', context)

def detail(request, car_id):
    context = {
        'car_id': car_id
    }
    return render(request, 'CarBank/details.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Django's own template system:

You can access variables, which you have passed into the context dictionary(in your view file), simply by using `{{ variable_name }}` tag in your template file.

### Update:

You need to retrieve object from your database in your view, like you did it in your `index` view. If you wan to retrieve single object from you databse in `detail` view, you can do this like this:

```
def detail(request, car_id):
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=car_id)
    context = {
        'car': car
    }
    return render(request, 'CarBank/details.html', context)
```

Then simply call `{{ car }}` in your template

read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Comment: Hi guy! I know it. but i don't know how can i retrieve data from database by this variable {{ Car_id }}.